# How can I change css of the first element with map function in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, map-function

I was thinking of changing the first element only on an array every time when the array is updated, I am not able to come up with any solution with this in ReactJS. for instance, if I have a list of users coming from an array, I just want to enable the first user only of that user's list.

Comment: This can be done with CSS. Please try and share if you get stuck.

Comment: What did you try so far? Do share a minimal repro.

Comment: li:first-of-type ?   array[0] ?   no code, no solution...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do have access to the `index` parameter, you can add a class only to the first element you just have to check whether `index` is 0 or not.

```js
arr.map((el, index) => {
  return <div className={index === 0 ? 'classOfFirstEl' : 'otherClass'}></div>
})
```

Comment: for me, this was a good answer for my inline styling with bootstrap. 
a DRY-er approach would be adjusting the css file and having different styling for the first-child.